# DataGrid cell edit Mode=TwoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` as below

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTemplate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Templates" Binding="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The two properties in question are as below

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _templates;
public ObservableCollection<string> Templates {
    get { return _templates; }
    set {
        if (_templates == value)
            return;

        _templates = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Templates");
    }
}

private string _selectedTemplate;
public string SelectedTemplate {
    get { return _selectedTemplate; }
    set {
        if (_selectedTemplate == value)
            return;

        _selectedTemplate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTemplate");
    }
}
```

I wish to perform `Edit` operation of the cells in the above `DataGrid` from the UI and the respective changes must be available in the bound properties.

Now as `String` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, editing cells in UI does not reflect changes in values in the property. So does anyone has any idea if there is a workaround for this so that I can achieve the required functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much choice here... Create a `TemplateModel` class with a `string Template` property. Make it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and change the following:

- Type of `Templates` to `ObservableCollection<TemplateModel>`
- Type of `SelectedTemplate` to `TemplateModel`
- Binding to `{Binding Path=Template, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`